# Probability and perfect squares

Tags: probability, education

An integer $n$ is randomly chosen from $1$ to $k^2$, where $k$ is an integer.
What is the probability that $n$ is a perfect square?

I know I have to first figure out the probability of getting a perfect square and then take the complement of this.

How would I go about? Thank you!!

Comment: No complement here. Hint: count the integers from 1 to k^2 that are perfect squares.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: How would you find the perfect squares between 1 and $k^2$? How many are there? How many numbers in total?…

Comment: would it be 1/k?

Comment: Exactly! There are $k$ numbers in $[1,\ldots,k^2]$ which are perfect squares, and there are $k^2$ total choices, so the probability of any one draw picking a perfect square is $\frac{k}{k^2} = \frac{1}{k}$.